btrfs mirror only important directories
I have 2 HDD disk, each with 2TB capacity,
and want to create one btrfs on these two disks.
we know btrfs support RAID. But what I want is:
I only need RAID1 on important directories, etc photo,
all pictures under photo should be stored on all disks. and if one disk fails. I can recovery all pictures from another disk.
does btrfs support this feature?

Yes and no. Technically it would be feasible, but the current implementation doesn't support specifying the redundancy preference per-directory or even per-subvolume. You can have a mix of some files as a single copy and some others as 'raid1' two copies, but whatever mode was set last will apply to all new data written to the entire volume, and the 'rebalance' tools will attempt to enforce a single mode to all existing data as well.
If you don't require the hot-swap disk replacement that RAID provides (which Btrfs doesn't handle very nicely anyway), I'd just go for single data and raid1 metadata – yes, keep the metadata as raid1 – and use a separate tool to back up your photos to a third drive.
(In fact, given how Btrfs filesystems can still die from various causes, I'd recommend using a separate tool to back up your important photos to a third drive regardless of Btrfs redundancy mode. RAID is not a backup method – it's more of a failover method to preserve uptime – and will do little against failure of the entire system.)

does zfs or else filesystem has this feature? I googled a lots, many people want this feature.

Sure, they do (and I'd like to have it as well), but when you think of it, what does it achieve? If one disk fails, you have to recover the OS and your other files from backups anyway, and if you have backups, the "mixed RAID" doesn't help you all that much. If both disks fail, or if the filesystem gets corrupted, and you didn't have backups because you thought RAID1 would save you... well, it's not going to help either.

I think Bcachefs might have this feature? Alternatively, Mergerfs, or... have two partitions, one with Btrfs single, the other with Btrfs raid1.

bcachefs has this feature. You can set it up per-file or per-directory using bcachefs setattr --data_replicas=2 /path/to/file. But you need to also have metadata replicas = 2 on the filesystem for this to be feasible. In your case, however, I wouldn't bother and create traditional fully mirrored setup.

What possessed them to use underscores in --long_option names, though...

Ask Kent Overstreet, not me :)

does bcachefs popular and active, seems no nas vendor use bcachefs
